# Orbeon 3.9 Liferay proxy portlet java.lang.NullPointerException Error with any user interaction

Tags: forms, liferay, portlet, orbeon

I'm trying to integrate Orbeon Forms 3.91 PE with Liferay 6.0.6.
I have installed Liferay, deployed orbeon.war, orbeon-proxy-portlet.war, copied the license file and created a file-local.xml properties (as described in the wiki).

Using the Form Builder I've created a form (the default content (one input field)).

Next I've added two pages in Liferay containing the portlets forms:
- one runner with my form
- second form refers to a form "contact" (the default one).

After integration with my form (eg try to save form) I'm getting error:

```
ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at line 55, column 65 of oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server.xpl (reading processor output: name='response', id='xforms-response')
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.checkUUIDInSession(XFormsStateManager.java:92)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.findOrRestoreDocument(XFormsStateManager.java:277)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.doIt(XFormsServer.java:152)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.access$000(XFormsServer.java:56)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer$1.readImpl(XFormsServer.java:88)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.TeeProcessor$TeeProcessorOutputImpl.readImpl(TeeProcessor.java:89)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:286)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$3.read(ProcessorImpl.java:315)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:365)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:330)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:313)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:186)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:664)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:729)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:248)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:664)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:729)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils.runProcessor(InitUtils.java:89)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService.service(ProcessorService.java:97)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServletDelegate.service(OrbeonServletDelegate.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

It looks like AJAX bug and the problem sessions managing.

After moving to form "contact" and interact with it I get the error:

```
[file:/C:/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/temp/upload__1b3fa11c_1388fbc4805__7ff4_00000095.tmp|null|null|000|true|false|false|false|[false|true|false|false|false|false]]
2012-07-16 14:47:20,240 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at line 55, column 65 of oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-server.xpl (reading processor output: name='response', id='xforms-response')
org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException: Session has expired. Unable to process incoming request.
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.checkUUIDInSession(XFormsStateManager.java:94)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.state.XFormsStateManager.findOrRestoreDocument(XFormsStateManager.java:277)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.doIt(XFormsServer.java:152)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer.access$000(XFormsServer.java:56)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer$1.readImpl(XFormsServer.java:88)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.TeeProcessor$TeeProcessorOutputImpl.readImpl(TeeProcessor.java:89)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:286)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$3.read(ProcessorImpl.java:315)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:365)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:330)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:313)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:186)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:664)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:729)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor.start(ConcreteChooseProcessor.java:248)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$5.run(PipelineProcessor.java:664)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.executeChildren(PipelineProcessor.java:729)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor.start(PipelineProcessor.java:661)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.InitUtils.runProcessor(InitUtils.java:89)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService.service(ProcessorService.java:97)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServletDelegate.service(OrbeonServletDelegate.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Since that time, this error also appears on my form (first one).

According to Firebug header contains JSESSIONID
(I can't attach images

```
Response:
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0
Content-Length  2299
Content-Type    application/xml;charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 16 Jul 2012 14:47:20 GMT
Expires Mon, 16 Jul 2012 14:47:20 GMT
Last-Modified   Mon, 16 Jul 2012 14:47:20 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request:
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  409
Content-Type    application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=BD09C08F33458793AB9DB94057DF7BDF; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/web/guest/contact
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

)

How can I fix it?
(both forms from localhost: 8080/orbeon work properly).

Comment: The proxy portlet is unfortunately broken in 3.9.1. Try [Orbeon Forms 4.0 M7](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/07/orbeon-forms-40-m7.html) instead.

Comment: @ebruchez any reference that it is broken? Thanks

Comment: The newest version M7 works fine. Earlier I've tried Orbeon Forms M6 and have the same problem. I thing reason was orbeon-proxy-portlet.war absence in M6.

Thank you for quick answer.

Comment: Great to hear it's working! I'll post my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy portlet is unfortunately broken in 3.9.1. Since that release we have implemented many fixes and improvements to the portlet, and the proxy portlet should work well with [Orbeon Forms 4.0 M7](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/07/orbeon-forms-40-m7.html).