# Orbeon 4 M11 + GlassFish 3.1.2 coused errors with HTTPURLConnection

Tags: glassfish, liferay, orbeon

I'm using Orbeon 4 M11 (but I've tried M9 also), GlassFish 3.1.2 and Liferay 6.1 GA2.
After deploy LR and Orbeon on GF and restart GF I went to:

```
 http://host:8080/orbeon/home/
```

and everything was ok, but when I tried use builder

```
 http://host:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/summary
```

I got error

> Oops, the page requested was not found!

I found this in orbeon.log:

```
2012-10-24 10:39:22,805 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/orbeon/builder/summary - Received request
2012-10-24 10:39:28,425 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Password must not be null                                                                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException                                                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore                 |engineGetKey                  |JavaKeyStore.java             | 107|
|sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS             |engineGetKey                  |JavaKeyStore.java             |  38|
|java.security.KeyStore                             |getKey                        |KeyStore.java                 | 763|
|com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl |<init>                        |SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java    | 113|
|com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$|engineInit                    |KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java    |  48|
|javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory                    |init                          |KeyManagerFactory.java        | 239|
|com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl |getDefaultKeyManager          |DefaultSSLContextImpl.java    | 170|
|com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl |<init>                        |DefaultSSLContextImpl.java    |  40|
|sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl          |newInstance0                  |NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.|    |
|sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl          |newInstance                   |NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.|  39|
|sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl      |newInstance                   |DelegatingConstructorAccessorI|  27|
|java.lang.reflect.Constructor                      |newInstance                   |Constructor.java              | 513|
|java.lang.Class                                    |newInstance0                  |Class.java                    | 355|
|java.lang.Class                                    |newInstance                   |Class.java                    | 308|
|java.security.Provider$Service                     |newInstance                   |Provider.java                 |1221|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException                                                                     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|java.security.Provider$Service                     |newInstance                   |Provider.java                 |1245|
|sun.security.jca.GetInstance                       |getInstance                   |GetInstance.java              | 220|
|sun.security.jca.GetInstance                       |getInstance                   |GetInstance.java              | 147|
|javax.net.ssl.SSLContext                           |getInstance                   |SSLContext.java               | 125|
|org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection |<clinit>                      |HTTPURLConnection.java        | 107|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException                                                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection |<clinit>                      |HTTPURLConnection.java        | 110|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPHandler       |openConnection                |HTTPHandler.java              |  28|
|java.net.URL                                       |openConnection                |URL.java                      | 945|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection                     |connect                       |Connection.scala              |  90|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  90|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           | 100|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 124|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.CacheableSubmissio|load                          |CacheableSubmission.java      | 148|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServerSharedInstancesCa|loadAndCache$1                |XFormsServerSharedInstancesCac|  80|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServerSharedInstancesCa|apply                         |XFormsServerSharedInstancesCac|  88|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServerSharedInstancesCa|apply                         |XFormsServerSharedInstancesCac|  88|
|scala.Option                                       |orElse                        |Option.scala                  | 218|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServerSharedInstancesCa|findContentOrLoad             |XFormsServerSharedInstancesCac|  88|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsServerSharedInstancesCa|findContentOrLoad             |XFormsServerSharedInstancesCac|    |
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.CacheableSubmissio|call                          |CacheableSubmission.java      | 119|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.CacheableSubmissio|call                          |CacheableSubmission.java      | 111|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           | 100|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.CacheableSubmissio|connect                       |CacheableSubmission.java      | 209|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmiss|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 456|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmiss|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 294|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline          |invoke                        |StandardPipeline.java         | 595|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 161|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |doService                     |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 331|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 231|
|com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper|call                          |ContainerMapper.java          | 317|
|com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper|service                       |ContainerMapper.java          | 195|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |invokeAdapter                 |ProcessorTask.java            | 860|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |doProcess                     |ProcessorTask.java            | 757|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |process                       |ProcessorTask.java            |1056|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter         |execute                       |DefaultProtocolFilter.java    | 229|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |executeProtocolFilter         |DefaultProtocolChain.java     | 137|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |execute                       |DefaultProtocolChain.java     | 104|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |execute                       |DefaultProtocolChain.java     |  90|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain             |execute                       |HttpProtocolChain.java        |  79|
|com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask           |doCall                        |ProtocolChainContextTask.java |  54|
|com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask            |call                          |SelectionKeyContextTask.java  |  59|
|com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask                        |run                           |ContextTask.java              |  71|
|com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker     |doWork                        |AbstractThreadPool.java       | 532|
|com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker     |run                           |AbstractThreadPool.java       | 513|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 662|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
2012-10-24 10:39:28,450 INFO  ProcessorService  - Session listener - Session created.
2012-10-24 10:39:28,455 WARN  XFormsServer  - xxforms:instance() - instance not found {instance id: "fr-form-metadata"}
2012-10-24 10:39:28,480 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection                                         |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError                                                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPHandler       |openConnection                |HTTPHandler.java              |  28|
|java.net.URL                                       |openConnection                |URL.java                      | 945|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection                     |connect                       |Connection.scala              |  90|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  90|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           | 100|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 124|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmiss|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 456|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmiss|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 294|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 139|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                | 139|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                | 139|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  43|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withDebug                     |Dispatch.scala                |  23|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 138|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                | 124|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                | 124|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  39|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 124|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispa|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  96|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline          |invoke                        |StandardPipeline.java         | 595|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 161|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |doService                     |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 331|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 231|
|com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper|call                          |ContainerMapper.java          | 317|
|com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper|service                       |ContainerMapper.java          | 195|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |invokeAdapter                 |ProcessorTask.java            | 860|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |doProcess                     |ProcessorTask.java            | 757|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask                 |process                       |ProcessorTask.java            |1056|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter         |execute                       |DefaultProtocolFilter.java    | 229|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |executeProtocolFilter         |DefaultProtocolChain.java     | 137|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |execute                       |DefaultProtocolChain.java     | 104|
|com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain               |execute                       |DefaultProtocolChain.java     |  90|
|com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain             |execute                       |HttpProtocolChain.java        |  79|
|com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask           |doCall                        |ProtocolChainContextTask.java |  54|
|com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask            |call                          |SelectionKeyContextTask.java  |  59|
|com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask                        |run                           |ContextTask.java              |  71|
|com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker     |doWork                        |AbstractThreadPool.java       | 532|
|com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker     |run                           |AbstractThreadPool.java       | 513|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 662|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
2012-10-24 10:39:28,495 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/orbeon/builder/summary"}
```

I've also configured persistence layer and tried debug but this error is thrown before my servlet.

I've tried also Orbeon v3.91 and it work correctly (I can build and save form) but I cannot use it with LR because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506962/orbeon-3-9-liferay-proxy-portlet-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-with-any-u)

Comment: This is strange. Did you change in any way the configuration from what comes out of the box (e.g. changing the `web.xml` or `properties-local.xml`, or some other configuration file)? If not, would you be able to try with Tomcat to see if works for you there?

Comment: Also, are you accessing the server over HTTPS? Would it work if it was HTTP? (I am not saying you should use HTTP instead of HTTPS, but trying to pinpoint the issue.)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply.

I'm using HTTP.
Tomcat works fine but I have to run it on GF.

I've changed properties-local (define persistence layer (and these properties works on tomcat)).
I've also tried delete all configuration changes but nothing changes (these errors still appears).
Regards

Comment: OK, got it, I was able to reproduce this with Glassfish 3.1, created a bug, and opened another Glassfish-specific question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. It will work after a simple change to your `domain.xml`. I updated my answer below to point to the installation instructions, which now mention how to do this. You'll let me know if this indeed works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error, you need to change your Glassfish configuration as documented in the [Orbeon Forms installation instructions for Glassfish 3.1](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-GlassFish-3.1).